# Is it required to escape '-' outside of a character class?

Tags: regex

Say I have the following regular expression:

```
/wall-e/
```

Does the `-` need to be escaped? Or is escaping the minus character only necessary if it is inside of a character class, such as in this example:

```
/[\s\-\+]/
```

Comment: This may be language dependent.

Comment: When asking regex questions, please specify the context. What language/flavor of regex are you using?

Comment: The answer is no. The hyphen as no special meaning outside a character class, it is not a regex special character. You don't need to escape it in a character class when it is at the begining or at the end, and with several languages (javascript, php) you don't need to escape it after a range or a shortcut character class. (you don't need to escape `+` everywhere in a character class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to escape the hyphen.

The hyphen is mostly a normal character in regular expressions.

Outside of a character class `[]` the hyphen has no special meaning, within a character class you can place a hyphen as the **first** or **last** character in the range. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to escape it in order to add it to your class.

**Note**: It is more common to find a hyphen placed first or last within a character class but by choosing to escape it instead is just as good.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a `-` does not need to be escaped, but you can probably find a language where this is not true.

Inside a character class, the convention is to make it the *first* character listed, and it should not be escaped. `[-_A-ZA-z1-9]` will work fine in most languages.

Outside a character class, the character `-` *usually* has no special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape `-` in `/wall-e/`

Comment: you don't need to escape `-` in character class also `/[\s\-\+]/`